# Add "new" banner on application icon

Tags: ios, xcode

Some new installed app have à 'new' banner on the top right side of the application icon.

Can i add this banner via programming?

Thanks

Comment: It's a badge and you can only control badge number: http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2012/03/22/how-to-add-badges-to-iphoneipad-icons/

Comment: Do not add the banner, because your app will likely be rejected.

Comment: Why a bad rate?  Question seems pertinent and important.  As i distribute also app via Entreprise account(not via app store), I found nice to show this icon banner.

Answer (score 2):

The OS does this once an app is downloaded and it is removed on the first run of the app. I am 99% sure you are unable to programatically add this banner to your app once it is removed. Only other solution would be to add the banner in the icon itself, or if you're looking for a way of notifying of "new" updates then make use of the Icon Badge Number.

Comment: (and adding the banner to the icon would most likely get your app rejected by apple)

Answer (score 1):

The new-banner is automatically displayed on icons of newly installed apps (from the App Store) when your device is running iOS6. Thus, I don't think it is possible nor necessary to apply it to an icon programmatically.